# How to add selling plan in graphql checkout shopify

Tags: react-native, graphql, shopify, shopify-app

I'm new to use Shopify graphql APIs. I create checkout using the below code. My Checkout working fine.

Now I want to add a product with a subscription plan.

I'm getting all plan data and id of the subscription plan added on product data.  On the Shopify backend, we use the [rechargepayments.com](https://rechargepayments.com) app that is installed in over admin. This is supported by JQuery and an over website subscription working fine.

```
const query = `
  mutation {
    checkoutCreate(input: {
      lineItems: [{ variantId: "${item.variantId}", quantity: 1, customAttributes: {key: "Shipping Styles", value: "Mixed"} }]
    }) {
      checkout {
         id
         webUrl
         lineItems(first: 5) {
           edges {
             node {
               title
               quantity
             }
           }
         }
      }
    }
  }`
  axios({
    url: `https://mystore.myshopify.com/api/2021-07/graphql.json`,
    method: 'POST',
    body: query,
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      onSuccess({ value: 'Checkout item added' })
    },
    onFailure: (err) => {
      console.log('updateCheckout err ', err);
      onFailure({ value: 'fail' })
    },
  });
```

Please help me how can I add a selling plan or a subscription using graphql from the mobile application.

Comment: You need to check here. https://shopify.dev/apps/subscriptions simple checkout API can't handle the subscriptions while creating the checkout using API